# How can I count matched rows individually?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my table structure:

```
-- qanda (stands for questions and answers)
+----+---------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------+------+
| id |  title  |                      content                  |  question_id |  user_id  | type |
+----+---------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------+------+
| 1  | title1  | this is a question                            | NULL         | 213423    | 0    |
| 2  | NULL    | this is an answer                             | 1            | 435344    | 1    |
| 3  | NULL    | this is another answer                        | 1            | 432435    | 1    |
| 4  | title2  | this is another question                      | NULL         | 124324    | 0    |
| 5  | NULL    | this is an answer for the second question     | 4            | 213423    | 1    |
| 6  | NULL    | this is another answer for the first question | 1            | 213423    | 1    |
+----+---------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------+------+
```

I want to *count the number of question and answers individually*. How can I do that?

The expected result for this user: `:user_id = 213423`

```
+--------+--------+
| q_num  | a_num  |
+--------+--------+
| 1      | 2      |
+--------+--------+
```

---

I can do that by two queries separately:

```
SELECT count(*) q_num FROM qanda WHERE user_id = :user_id AND question_id IS NULL

SELECT count(*) a_num FROM qanda WHERE user_id = :user_id AND question_id IS NOT NULL
```

Can I do that in one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do:

```
SELECT count(questionid) as q_num,
       sum(questionid is null) as a_num
FROM qanda
WHERE user_id = :user_id ;
```

`count()` with a column or expression counts the number of non-`NULL` values -- exactly what you want to do.  MySQL treats boolean values as integers in a numeric context, with 1 for true and 0 for false.

You could also write this as:

```
(count(*) - count(questionid)) as a_num
```

or

```
sum(case when questionid is null then 1 else 0 end) as a_num
```

EDIT:

Using type, you can use a variant:

```
select sum(type = 0) as q_num, sum(type = 1) as a_num
```

Comment: In your last query, there are two `a_num`. One of them should be `q_num`. Thank you, upvote

Comment: @MartinAJ . . . That wasn't a query.  That was two ways of doing the same thing.

Comment: Ok well, I didn't ask my question accurate enough. Actually I've one more column named `type`. It contains `0` for questions and `1` for answers. Can you please tell me how can I handle it now?

Comment: Sorry to ping you again, I think that condition for **answers** is redundant.  You can simply write `sum(type) as a_num` *(no need to `sum(type = 1)`)*. Am I right?

Comment: @MartinAJ . . . Yes, you can.  However, that seems a little dangerous because other types might appear.  If the column were called `isAnswer`, then I'd be more confident that the value is always 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
 SUM(question_id IS NULL) a_num,
 SUM(question_id IS NOT NULL) q_num 
 FROM qanda 
 WHERE user_id = :user_id
```

Try above query.

As written in above query I had used `question_id IS NULL` it will generate 1 for true and 0 for false so `SUM(question_id IS NOT NULL)` will generate exact count of question.

Same is work for answer also.

Comment: Comparing anything to NULL yields to NULL. To test if a column contains NULL, use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `SUM` with a `CASE` statement will accomplish this.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN question_id IS NULL 
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
           END) AS q_num,
       SUM(CASE WHEN question_id IS NOT NULL 
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
           END) AS a_num 
FROM qanda
WHERE user_id = :user_id
```

Output (For `user_id = '213423'`)

```
q_num a_num
1     2
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4923c/2/0